# How to send instance variables when rendering a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, rendering

I want to render action if my model is not valid.

`render "book_page"`

https://gist.github.com/f7259eb79d1f2c951036

But for now `@prices_per_night` and `@number_of_nights` are nil when i click submit button. How to prevent this?

I tried to move this form to partial but it now happend, because I cant render only partial. Or Am I wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by " `@prices_per_night` and `@number_of_nights` are nil.  How to Prevent this?" How is this relevant, are you trying to set those as global variables?

Comment: I think you may be confusing what to refer to variables as, check out their definitions [here](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/variables.html), should your title be "How to send _instance_ variables when rendering a _partial_"??

Comment: Sorry, You are right, just changed title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `render` does *not* make Rails call the relevant method, `book_page`, in the controller. It proceeds directly to `book_page.html.erb` and, at this point, no method has set your instance variables so they appear `nil`.

Comment: Ok, so which method should i use instead of render?

Comment: I don't think anything stops you from calling book_page explicitly before calling render. Perhaps you should do both (or set the instance variables and call render) in some appropriate helper method.